# json marshal araylist in golang

Tags: json, go, marshalling

Hi there I back to ask again 
sorry if you guys think I lack of searching but been doing this for hours and I still don't get it why

I have a controller like this in Golang :

```
c3 := router.CreateNewControllerInstance("index", "/v4")
c3.Post("/insertEmployee", insertEmployee)
```

and using **Postman** to throw this arraylist request , the request is like this

```
[{
  "IDEmployee": "EMP4570787",
  "IDBranch": "ALMST",
  "IDJob": "PRG",
  "name": "Mikey Ivanyushin",
  "street": "1 Bashford Point",
  "phone": "9745288064",
  "join_date": "2008-09-18",
  "status": "fulltime"
},{
  "IDEmployee": "EMP4570787",
  "IDBranch": "ALMST",
  "IDJob": "PRG",
  "name": "Mikey Ivanyushin",
  "street": "1 Bashford Point",
  "phone": "9745288064",
  "join_date": "2008-09-18",
  "status": "fulltime"
}]
```

and also I have 2 Struct like this

```
type EmployeeRequest struct {
    IDEmployee string `json: "id_employee"`
    IDBranch   string `json: "id_branch"    `
    IDJob      string `json: "id_job"   `
    Name       string `json: "name" `
    Street     string `json: "street"   `
    Phone      string `json: "phone"    `
    JoinDate   string `json: "join_date"    `
    Status     string `json: "status"   `
    Enabled int `json: "enabled"    `
    Deleted int `json: "deletedstring"`
}

type ListEmployeeRequest struct {
    ListEmployee []EmployeeRequest `json: "request"`
}
```

for some reason the problem start here , when I try to run my function to read the json that I send from Postman

here is the function that I try to run

```
func insertEmployee(ctx context.Context) {
    tempReq := services.ListEmployeeRequest{}

    temp1 := ctx.ReadJSON(&tempReq.ListEmployee)

    var err error
    if err = ctx.ReadJSON(temp1); config.FancyHandleError(err) {
        fmt.Println("err readjson ", err.Error())
    }
    parsing, errParsing := json.Marshal(temp1)
        fmt.Println("", string(parsing))
    fmt.Print("", errParsing)
}
```

the problem occur on the line **if err = ctx.ReadJSON(temp1); config.FancyHandleError(err)** 
it tell me that I got unexpected end of JSON input am I doing something wrong there when I throw the request from Postman? or I made a wrong validation code?

can someone tell me what to do next for me to be able to read the JSON that I throw from postman?

thanks for your attention and help , much love <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues here:

1. Tag names don't match the JSON input, e.g. `id_employee` vs `IDEmployee`.
2. Your tag syntax is not correct, it shows when you run `go vet`, it should be `json:"id_employee"`
3. You don't need another `List` struct, if you use it your json should be `{"requests":[...]}`. Instead you can deserialize a slice:

   ```
   var requests []EmployeeRequest
   if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &requests); err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   ```

You can see a running version here: https://play.golang.org/p/HuycpNxE6k8

Comment: is this j in json.unmarshal([]byte(j),&requests) refer to my json that I send from postman?

Comment: yes, `j` should be the json you have sent from the client.

Answer (score 1):

```
type EmployeeRequest struct {
    IDEmployee string `json:"IDEmployee"`
    IDBranch   string `json:"IDBranch"`
    IDJob      string `json:"IDJob"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Street     string `json:"street"`
    Phone      string `json:"phone"`
    JoinDate   string `json:"join_date"`
    Status     string `json:"status"`

    Enabled int `json:"enabled"`
    Deleted int `json:"deletedstring"`
}
```

some of json tags didn't match with fields.